# Change object key property in reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have two values from the server - old value and new value. Inside my redux store I need to change object key from old value to a new value (edit key value) and attach array of items from old object key to replaced new object key. What is the best approach to do it?

I tried do it something like this:

```
const handleEditFilter = (state, { payload }) => {
  const { newValue, oldValue } = payload;
  return {
    ...state,
    regions: {
      ...state.regions,
      list: {
        ...state.regions.list,
        [newValue]: [...state.regions.list[oldValue]],
      },
    },
  };
};
```

But it's just create a new object with array items from old array. How to actually replace key name of object and attach items from old key?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, copy the inner list:

```
const list = { ...state.regions.list };
```

then replace the value:

```
list[newValue] = list[oldValue];
delete list[oldValue];
```

Then update state:

```
return {
  ...state,
  regions: {
     ...state.regions,
     list
  }
};
```

To perform immutable operations on nested objects, I prefer to use a library, e.g. [icepick](https://github.com/aearly/icepick), which would make the operation a bit more readable (a chain of `getIn`, `unsetIn` and `setIn`).